# Creating webpages for my Professor

Tags: web, dreamweaver, html

I have to come up with some good looking webpages for my professor which will include pages for topics like research work, current students, alumni, paper published, etc.

Can someone please help me by leading me to some good tutorial in website development ? I have planned to use Adobe Dreamweaver for this ? Is this a good software to start with as i have no prior experience with website development or creating webpages.

Comment: You asked this several months ago, but I just posted a small program designed particularly for creating professor websites.  You can find a link to a demo website on my blog.  It's not fancy, but it is much better looking than a typical professor website, and it is flexible and easy to use (according to me, anyways...)   http://bit.ly/k6vms7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dreamweaver will be hard to learn if you cannot pick up the tools properly, because if you are not using the tools within Dreamweaver you might as well use a different text editor with syntax highlighting :

- Notepad (or Notepad++)
- Vim/Emacs
- Coda

Along with a ftp and a local server to test (XAMPP/IIS) your webpages before displaying it to the public.

University webpages are very simple and not very heavy on design (at least from what I have seen).

So you are really only going to need to know what the following  mean

- `<html>`
- `<body>`
- `<head>`
- `<meta>`
- `<title>`
- `<p>`
- `<strong>`
- `<a>`
- `<img>`

and focus on the content being served.

And this is a bare html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <title>Test</title>
      <style type="text/css">
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
   </body>
</html>
```

Please *do not* use w3schools. Use it for a quick reminder every once in a while as to what certain tags do but do not use it for practice.

So start off with [Opera Web Standards Curriculum](http://www.opera.com/company/education/curriculum/) as said there:

> This is a web standards course
>   comprised of several articles, aimed
>   at pretty much anyone who wants to
>   learn web standards–based web design
>   from scratch. It is intended to take
>   the reader from nothing more than a
>   basic familiarity with browsing the
>   web, to being competent with CSS and
>   HTML, and have basic knowledge of
>   JavaScript and how it fits in to the
>   puzzle.

If you still choose to go the Dreamweaver way here are some supporting articles

[Getting Started with Dreamweaver CS3](http://www.adobe.com/devnet-archive/dreamweaver/articles/getting_started_dreamweaver_cs3.html)
[Getting started with Dreamweaver CS4](http://www.adobe.com/devnet-archive/dreamweaver/articles/dwcs4_getting_started.html)
[Learn Dreamweaver CS5](http://tv.adobe.com/show/learn-dreamweaver-cs5/)

Comment: Thanks a lot Philippe.Actually, i am in need of creating webpages which look relatively good than the usual university webpages (for professors) that we see. Bottom line is i do not have to do something as complex as Flash, dynamic webpages, nor something which is very trivial. So, would you still suggest me Dreamweaver for doing something as what i have described above ?

Comment: @Jeeka you are going to have to do it in iterations. You will have to start with something trivial. Get the content and semantics right *then* incrementally add things you want. Also with Dreamweaver preview option you may not be seeing what the browser is actually putting out as content. You could definitely do it in Dreamweaver but you are looking at a very steep slope to understand everything while ensuring your appearance for the website. Once you have the content down you can start learning CSS to start moving stuff around and working the design (appearance of it)

Comment: @Jeeka it is also a matter of time investment. Using a more basic text editor gives (in my opinion) a better grasp of what is going on, you can add syntax highlighting to at least separate info but the bottom line is that you get the structure from the ground up. If you are rushed for time and you *did* know how to use Dreamweaver then the code completion, WYSIWYG views, div and table inserts would definitely help speed up the process. But in this case you are trying to learn the tool and the language so as I said before a steep slope. Might as well learn the language first then the tool .

Comment: Thanks you so much for the insight. I really appreciate it ! I will take your points going forward.

Answer (score 2):

**DreamWeaver: Not bad!**

Just stay away from 'template' feature (updating DW templates makes a big MESS).

**DreamWeaver Kick Start**

Here's some basic information about DreamWeaver : http://www.haverford.edu/acc/docs/software/dreamweaver/welcome.htm

**Website Templates**

You can even skip designing your website from scratch and find a pre-fabricated one that suits you, with sites like these : http://www.steves-templates.com/

**Web Design Kick Start**

In case you're still set on designing a website from scratch (a great idea! but more work), it's hard to give out just one link for web-design. I think webdesign has two components : knowing HTML/CSS/etc, and making it "work". Here's a webpage (ugh ads) full of good advice by example, rather than by novel. 
http://www.webpagesthatsuck.com/

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information rlb.usa. I appreciate it very much !. Since you said 'Dreamweaver is no bad' would you suggest any other better software for doing this ?